# info.selectionText is undefined - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hotkeys

I have a handy extension that I use for work to make browsing different files/web pages more efficient. The extension creates a context menu and I highlight some text and it allows me to jump directly to that webpage by adding that selected text into the URL.

It works really well so far but I am currently trying to add hot keys to this extension and I am really unsure on how to proceed.

I have tried to use messaging but I could not get it to work for this application.

I am able to call the chrome.commands.onCommand and have it open up a new tab, but I can not get it to read my highlighted text.

```
//background.js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
          if (command == 'funcA'){
              chrome.tabs.create({
                url: "www.company.com/ordernumber/"  + info.selectionText.trim()
                })}
        });

function orders(info,tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "www.company.com/ordernumber/" + info.selectionText.trim()
                      })}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Order Number",
  contexts:["selection"],
  onclick: orders
  })




//manifest.JSON
{
    "name": "quickLinks",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
      "16": "ql.png",
      "48": "ql.png",
      "128": "ql.png"
    },
    "description": "",
    "permissions": [
      "contextMenus"
     ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["backgrounds.js"]
    },
    "commands": {
          "funcA": {
            "suggested_key": {
              "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1"
            },
            "description": "Executes Func A"
          }},
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
      }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "ql.png",
      "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    }

}
```

The context menu works as expected.
The hotkey fires correctly but info.selectionText.trim() will show undefined.  I believe it is a scope issue, but I don't know how to fix it or if its even possible.

Thanks.
This is what I tried next and got "Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
          if (command == 'funcA'){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'getSelection().toString()'}, data => {
              chrome.tabs.create({
                url: "http://www.company.com/orderNumber/" + data[0]
              })})
          }})
```

Comment: As you can see `info` is not defined and not passed inside chrome.commands.onCommand so that won't work. What you need is an additional content script which you can run even without messaging like chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'getSelection().toString()'}, data => { /* data[0] is the selected text */ }) more info [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: I added a short update to my code.

I am now getting [0] as undefined.  Not really sure what I did incorrectly.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I can't know, right? I can only guess. Maybe it's inside an iframe, in which case you'll need to add `allFrames:true` and some probably nontrivial checks to only process the actually active iframe (I've seen an answer for that long time ago so google it up). Or maybe your extension doesn't have permissions for that tab's URL.

Comment: You are awesome.  I finally got it working.

I was testing my extension on the chrome://extensions page (for which I do not have permissions), which was why I was unable to get a result.

I also had to update my permissions on the manifest to make this work correctly.

Thanks again and I really appreciate your help.